# Could book recommendations for non-equilibrium statistical mechanics be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates, reopen, resource-recommendation

I was looking for books on non equilibrium statistical mechanics and found [the question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226929/71413) severely lacking in good answers. Also the reason for closing it was a "duplicate" question about statistical field theory books, which I don't even know what that is although I had a course in non-equilibrium statistical mechanics in uni.
Can this question please be unlocked?

Comment: What do you want to do? Add a new answer?

Comment: Yes. Maybe someone else wants to as well who knows.

Answer (score 2):

The post has now been reopened as statistical mechanics and statistical field theory are different topics.